# Why is my fadeOut() method not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my code snippet, it seems that the `fadeOut()` method is not working and the second image is loaded immediately. I want to fade-out the first image after the animation of first image completes. Please suggest your valuable ideas.

```
var i = 0;
var images = ['images/bg1.jpg', 'images/bg2.jpg'];
var image = $('#bg');
setInterval(function() {
    image.animate({
        width: "2000px",
        top: "-90px",
        right: "-45px"
    },

    10000,
            function() {
                $('#bg').fadeOut(5000);
                image.css('background-image', 'url(' + images[i++] + ')');
                image.css("width", "1900px");
                image.css("top", "0px");
                image.css("right", "0px");
            });
    if (i == images.length) {
        i = 0;
    }

}, 1000);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: am i'm seeing this correct? You have an interval every 1 second that runs a animation that runs for 10 seconds..? I wouldn't recommend that ;]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use -

```
$('#bg').fadeOut(5000, function(){
            image.css('background-image', 'url(' + images[i++] + ')');
            image.css("width", "1900px");
            image.css("top", "0px");
            image.css("right", "0px");
});
```

instead of ,

```
$('#bg').fadeOut(5000);
            image.css('background-image', 'url(' + images[i++] + ')');
            image.css("width", "1900px");
            image.css("top", "0px");
            image.css("right", "0px");
```

In short, you are not waiting for the fadeout animation to finish.

**EDIT**

Bring the index check, before the image is assigned like this -

```
  function() {   
                if (i == images.length) {
                   i = 0;
                }
                $('#bg').fadeOut(5000);
                image.css('background-image', 'url(' + images[i++] + ')');
                image.css("width", "1900px");
                image.css("top", "0px");
                image.css("right", "0px");
            });
```

Comment: Hi ActiveHigh, Thanks for your swift reply. The fadeOut works fine, but the second image is not getting loaded.

Comment: the reason i think is you need to insert 'if (i == images.length) i = 0; also into the callback

Comment: @user2118784, sorry last comment was wrong, take the call to before the image is changed.

Comment: Hi webkit & ActiveHigh: It works fine, but my footer goes up when the full code has been executed.

Comment: Sorry footer remains at same place. The content below the banner goes up and down.

Comment: Hi Active, Suggest me how to avoid the content goes up for each iteration.

Comment: @user2118784 I'm pretty sure your content goes up because when you fadeOut makes it 'display:none;'.. I'll edit my below answer to show you a better  way..

Answer (score 1):

this is the full solution:

```
    image.fadeOut(5000, function() {
        image.css({'background-image': 'url(' + images[i++] + ')', width:1900, top:0, right:0});
        if (i==images.length) i=0;
    })
```

EDIT: use opacity instead so you won't loose the height of the content:

```
image.animate({opacity:0}, 5000, function() {
            image.css({'background-image': 'url(' + images[i++] + ')', width:1900, top:0, right:0, opacity:1});
            if (i==images.length) i=0;
        })
```

Comment: though I'm still kind of confused exactly what you're going for.. you want the images to fadeOut and then reappear? or fade back in?

Comment: Hi webkit, Thanks. It is working fine. Actually I am creating a customized banner. We need to add $("#bg").css("opacity", 1); at the end. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call your code after finishing fadeOut, like below :

```
$('#bg').fadeOut(5000, function(){
          image.css('background-image', 'url(' + images[i++] + ')');
          image.css("width", "1900px");
          image.css("top", "0px");
          image.css("right", "0px");
});
```

[fadeOut API document](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/)